# Setting session value on redirection of page in new window

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, session

Searchbox.cs file

```
protected void SearchButtonClicked()
{
    Session["returnToSearch"]="/content-search-result?searchtext=test&searchmode=anyword";
    Response.Redirect("/detailPage.aspx");
}
```

On detailPage.aspx

```
 <a href='<%= Session["returnToSearch"] %>'>Return to Search</a>
```

I have set session in the cs file and if redirecting to another page opening in new window with `target_blank`. If I search test the `returnToSearch` loads the previous value if stored in session else blank value but if I reload the page it will sets the correct updated value.

searchbox.aspx

```
   <div class="search-box">
            <div class="searchBox" id="SearchBox_pnlSearch">
                <label style="display: none;" id="SearchBox_lblSearch" for="SearchBox_txtWord">Search for:</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="SearchBox_txtWord" maxlength="1000" autocomplete="off">
                <input type="submit" class="btn btn-default" id="SearchBox_btnSearch" value="Search">

                <div class="predictiveSearchHolder" id="SearchBox_pnlPredictiveResultsHolder">
                    <div class="predictiveSearchResults" id="SearchBox" style="display: none;">
                        <div class="predictiveSearchCategory nonSelectable">Default Search</div>
                        <a onclick="return callForReturn(this);" target="_blank" href="/Art/Test-Name" style="display: block; color: black" class="selectedResult">Test Name</a>

                        <a onclick="return callForReturn(this);" target="_blank" href="/Art/TEst-Art" style="display: block; color: black">TEst Art</a>

                        <a onclick="return callForReturn(this);" target="_blank" href="/Art/Test" style="display: block; color: black">Test</a>

                        <a onclick="return callForReturn(this);" target="_blank" href="/Art/Test-New" style="display: block; color: black">Test New </a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>    
        </div>

<script type="text/javascript">
     function callForReturn(obj) { $(obj).closest('.searchBox').find('input[type="submit"]').‌​click(); } 

    $('.searchBox input.form-control').keyup(function (event) {
              if (event.keyCode == 13) {

                var getAnchor = $('.predictiveSearchResults').find('a');
                $(getAnchor).attr('target', '_blank');
                var getLinkUrl = $('.predictiveSearchResults').find('a.selectedResult').attr('href');
                if($(getAnchor).hasClass('selectedResult')){
                    callForReturn(getAnchor);
                    var redirectWindow = window.open(getLinkUrl, '_blank');

                    $.ajax({
                        type: 'POST',   
                        url: '/echo/json/',
                        success: function (data) {
                            redirectWindow.location;
                        }
                    });

                }
              }
            }

</script>
```

Comment: Where is the javascript?

Comment: 'function callForReturn(obj)
 {
  $(obj).closest('.searchBox').find('input[type="submit"]').click();
 }'
This is link for predctive search click
'<a style="display: block; color: black" href='<%# SearchResultUrl() %>' >'